# Show/Hide elements/tags for different users in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to make an EA-Project where I and some other people can see all information but some others should only see selected information.
Is it possible to create an EA-Project and do some settings so some defined elements or tags or element information are shown or hidden to defined users?

Or do i have to create two seperate EA-Projects?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, if a user has access to an element, he has access to all its properties.

What you *can* do is hide parts of the model. There are two options:

### Hide Project Root

You can use a group lock to hide a project root from users outside of that group. This is mainly a usability feature as it doesn't prevent users from accessing the contents of the hidden project root in other ways.
From the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/team_support/hideprojectroot.html):

> When you set a Group Lock on a Root Node, you can also select a checkbox to hide the Package in the Browser window from users who are not members of the locking group or Administrators. If you change the type of lock, or remove the lock altogether, the Package becomes visible to all users.
>
> This feature hides the Root Package and its contents from initial view in the Browser window. It does not prevent the contents of the Package from being exposed in Model Searches. If you want to completely hide a Package from groups of users, consider Pro Cloud Server Visibility Levels.

### Pro Cloud Server Visibility Levels

This is the real thing. It uses database row level security to prevent certain users from seeing the information stored in these rows. You'll need Pro Cloud Server to setup these visibility levels.

See the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_repository/visibility_levels.html) for more information

Comment: Thnak you very much for your fast answer :)